# Executing the PAF test scripts in GitLab

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

While executing the PAF test scripts in GitLab, it will throw error "Job's log exceeded limitation". How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

For resolving the issue either you can approach the tool team for increasing the log file size.

In eclipse-->src---> log4j.properties file you can use DEBUG instead of ERROR.

```
#log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE, CONSOLE
log4j.rootLogger = ERROR, FILE, CONSOLE
```